# New .scss file cannot be detected by the website

Tags: html, css, npm, sass

I have no prior experience of scss and I am using a [Portfolio Template](https://github.com/cobiwave/simplefolio) for my portfolio website.
I added one more section to the website. If I am defining a style in any _file.scss file which was present priorly, it is working fine but when I create a new _filename.scss file for it. It is not detecting the style from that file.

Do I need to configure something before running npm start or npm install.

Comment: you need to import it in `styles.scss`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to Import the file in your main scss file.
ex.:

given:

> _filename.scss

usage in the main scss file:

```
@import "filename";
```

Remember***
Dont write the underscore in there, the underscore means, that it is a (scss) file that is going to be imported.